# Recursive Selection sort Java

Tags: java, recursion, pseudocode, selection-sort

I've been looking for a recursive selection sort, using only 2 parameters:

- The array that has to be sorted
- a value k, which indicates till which
  element it has to be sorted.

Example: SelectionSort(array[] a, int k) with a being {6,3,5,7,2} and k being 2 will sort the first 3 elements, and will keep the last elements untouched.

I was thinking about starting with an if-statement for k being 0, and if that was the case, it would just return the array as it is, since you cant sort an array of size 1.
Something like:

```
public int[] sort(int[] a){
    a = selectionSort(a, n-1);
    return a;
}

public int[] selectionSort(int[] a, int k){
    if (k = 0){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        selectionSort(a, k-1 );
               ... (part i really don't know)
}
```

I have no clue how to do  the 'else' part since I only know that it has to call the method again.
I'm not allowed to create other methods. I also need to make sure I use exactly 2 parameters, nothing more, nothing less.

I have to work it out in pseudocode, but I understand some Java, so if someone could help me by using either pseudo, or Java, it would be so helpful

Comment: Hi and welcome, while this would be an interesting challenge, it is not the philosophy of the site to provide code written from scratch. You probably should begin with it, do your best and come back when you're stuck with something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some remarks to your code:

- Your methods `sort` and `selectionSort` don't need to return an `int[]` array,
  since the array object `a` stays the same all the time.
  It is only the content within this array which changes.
  Hence, you can use `void` as return-type.
- In your `if` use `(k == 0)` instead of `(k = 0)`

You already figured out the first part.
Here it is how you can do the second part in pseudo code:

```
public void selectionSort(int[] a, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        selectionSort(a, k-1 );
        find x such that a[x] is the smallest of a[k] ... a[a.length - 1]
        if (a[k-1] > a[x]) {
            swap a[k-1] and a[x]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure you are able to refine the pseudo code to real Java code.

Answer (score 2):

By doing a simple google search, I found the biggest part of the code below on [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-selection-sort/). I added the `selectionSort` method myself to suit your parameters.

```
    public void selectionSort(int a[], int n) 
    {
      recurSelectionSort(a, n, 0);
    }

    // Recursive selection sort. n is size of a[] and index
    // is index of starting element.
    static void recurSelectionSort(int a[], int n, int index)
    {
          
        // Return when starting and size are same
        if (index == n)
           return;
      
        // calling minimum index function for minimum index
        int k = minIndex(a, index, n-1);
      
        // Swapping when index nd minimum index are not same
        if (k != index){
           // swap
           int temp = a[k];
           a[k] = a[index];
           a[index] = temp;
        }
        // Recursively calling selection sort function
        recurSelectionSort(a, n, index + 1);
    }

    // Return minimum index
    static int minIndex(int a[], int i, int j)
    {
        if (i == j)
            return i;
  
        // Find minimum of remaining elements
        int k = minIndex(a, i + 1, j);
  
        // Return minimum of current and remaining.
        return (a[i] < a[k])? i : k;
    }
```